# Creating a network structure in AWS - VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, amazon-web-services

I have a question about two things: one is the feasibility of spending all our structure to AWS and the other would be a starting point for finding information to perform, if feasible.

I currently have a physical office that has the following basic structure:

- Internet ADSL modem (/ Static IP)
- Router TP-Link R600VPN V2
- 4 servers, two Windows (with LDAP and another with IIS) and two Ubuntu Server for web applications NodeJS + PHP

We have customers that established VPN Site-to-Site IPSec connections to remotely access they resources (SAP) and a PPTP VPN for remote employee access (when connected, we can access customers resources through the VPN Site-to-Site. If I knew draw, it would be something like this:

[image]

In short: in my laptop I connect via PPTP on the router and thought VPN site-tosite I can access customer systems/resources.

Today I already can migrate:

- The 4 servers to EC2 instances
- The PPTP VPN for access to this structure (4 servers) on AWS

But I do not know if it is possible to create a site-to-site connection with my customers in AWS and then connect to the AWS trought PPTP VPN from my local machine (laptop) to access customer resources using Site-to-Site IPSec. I read about VPC but not I could understand if what we have here really is possible to do using the AWS cloud. This can be done? What would the starting point to try to create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood what you are trying to do. But based on my understanding of the problem, I think you have two options:

**1- Using VPN (similar to your Site-to-Site):** the prerequisite is that your router us supported by AWS to create a VPN.

- Create a VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) which is kind of your own virtual environment you could create on ESX for example, but this one is on the cloud. You can have multiple VPCs on AWS.
- Once you've created your VPC, you need to create your VPN from your router to the virtual gateway on your VPC.

**2- Create a VPN instance (OpenVPN)** on your VPC and install the VPN client on your laptop to be able to connect to your instances in the VPC.

Not sure if this is for support/admin needs otherwise the second solution will not be of help.

Comment: That's right, I have created the VPC VPN Site-to-Site and started a EC2 instance with OpenVPN and worked fine (just OpenVPN configuration that's not so easy - ip forwarding is necessary). Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is. But you could take an AMI ready for OpenVPN or do it yourself by issuing this command:

"echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"